# How to fix the app name in MKMapView's NSErrors?

Tags: mapkit, nserror

One of `MKMapViewDelegate`'s methods is:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didFailToLocateUserWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

If the error is that the user didn't grant location services permission to the app then the error is `MKLocationErrorDomain Code=0 "Location Services Off" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Location Services Off, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Turn on Location Services in Settings > Privacy to allow (null) to determine your current location}`

I think that the `(null)` is supposed to be the name of my app. What should I do to achieve that?

I could fix it like this but it seems like a hack:
`NSString *fixedLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = [error.localizedRecoverySuggestion stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"(null)" withString:@"AppName"];`